# Checking if Characters in Strings Match Up Within a Dictionary

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, character

I'm trying to see if a key and its value in a dictionary share any common letters. Both the keys and the values are strings and I know I can access the characters in the strings using the .characters method but I'm not sure how to check to see if any of the characters in one match any of the other characters in the other.

For example, if I had a dictionary of pets as:

```
var pets = ["cat" : "dog", "rat" : "snake"]
```

Comparing "cat" and "dog" would return true because no letters match but comparing "rat" and "snake" would return false because they shared an "a".

I'm pretty new to coding so it might be something very simple that I haven't learned yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `Set` of the `characters`, and then get the common letters by finding the `intersection` of this set with the other words' characters. If the intersection is empty, then there are no letters in common, and vice versa.

Here's how that would look:

```
extension String {
    func hasLettersInCommon(with other: String) -> Bool {
        let selfLetters = Set(self.characters)
        let otherLetters = other.characters
        let commonLetters = selfLetters.intersection(otherLetters)
        return !commonLetters.isEmpty
    }
}

var pets = ["cat" : "dog", "rat" : "snake"] 

for (key, value) in pets {
    print(key, value, key.hasLettersInCommon(with: value))
}
```

prints:

> rat snake true
>
> cat dog false

Comment: That seemed to get me on the right track. But what about case insensitivity? So if I had ["Goat" : "Pig"], I would still want to know that they share a letter, even though its uppercase in one and lowercase in the other. I believe the current solution would find that false because it is case sensitive, right?

Comment: @tjcarney89 Lowercase the strings before comparing them